# Laravel 5 Hash::check returns true with different cipher and APP_KEY values

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am migrating a Laravel 5.2 app to 5.3. In the migration notes, it is noted that the cipher needs to be updated to AES-256-CBC and the app key will need to be regenerated.

> If you are still using an Mcrypt based cipher in your config/app.php configuration file, you should update the cipher to AES-256-CBC and set your key to a random 32 byte string which may be securely generated using php artisan key:generate.

Now, I did as requested and I was expecting that passwords saved with Hash::make() would no longer work. Nevertheless, they are still working. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, passwords are [hashed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing) using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` and not the `APP_KEY`, so changing the key doesn't affect old passwords.

The `APP_KEY` and ciphers are used for [Encryption and Decryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption) of data.